# Getting index of a sublist specific to an element in it

Tags: python

How can I get the index of a list inside of another list but, I want to find the index by using an element of that “inside” list in Python? for example I have

```
 [["dead"["brain.txt"],["alive",["grail.txt"]].
```

Now I want to find the index of the second list but using the element alive. So if I have an input and I write alive, it should give me the index 1, in which alive is stored.p

Comment: Use a `for` loop?

Comment: Seems that your "[" and "]" doesn't match. Please correct it

Comment: Generally, `list`s should be homogeneous. Until you know what you're doing, you should always move to a different data structure if you're mixing types like this.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the syntax of your nested list, here's a way to get the index with [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a list comprehension:

```
>>> data = [["dead", ["brain.txt"]],["alive",["grail.txt"]]]
>>> next(i for i, v in enumerate(data) if 'alive' in v)
1
>>> next(i for i, v in enumerate(data) if 'dead' in v)
0
>>> next(i for i, v in enumerate(data) if 'nothere' in v)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

You can define a default value if no index is found :

```
>>> next((i for i, v in enumerate(data) if 'nothere' in v), 'NotFound')
'NotFound'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a class to this?

```
lst = [["dead", ["brain.txt"]], ["alive", ["grail.txt"]]]


class MyList(object):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self._lst = lst

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        for idx, values in enumerate(self._lst):
            if item in values:
                return idx
        return KeyError()


print(MyList(lst)['alive'])
```